# Java:Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) error with some commands,but works with other command

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cmd = {"which", "hive"};

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader( proc.getInputStream() ) );

    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }

    proc.waitFor();   
}
```

In my terminal:

```
which hive:/home/as/hive/bin/hive
which gcc:/usr/bin/gcc
```

But when I run this java code:

```
which hive:no result
which gcc:/usr/bin/gcc
```

I've added `$HIVE_HOME` into `~/.bashrc` (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit and Java 8), so what should I do now?

Comment: If you want to see errors, I suggest you read the error stream.  Or you can combine the two streams into one to make it easier to read.

Comment: How are you running Java?  Are you sure hive is in your PATH when you run Java?  Try printing `System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PATH"));`

Answer (score 1):

The command `which` looks in all the directories specified in the environment variable `PATH`. On Linux, the directories are separated by a colon (`:`) and on Windows by a semicolon (`;`).

You can check what `PATH` is being passed to `which` by doing a

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```

And you can pass a different path to `Runtime.exec`:

```
String[] env = { "PATH=/home/as/hive/bin" };
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

If you do that, it `which` will find the `hive` command (but it will not longer find `gcc` unless you also add `/usr/bin` to the `PATH`, as in `PATH=/home/as/hive/bin:/usr/bin`)

Comment: as@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH;
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/as/hadoop/bin:/home/as/hadoop/sbin:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/as/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin:/home/as/hbase/bin:/home/as/hive/bin

Comment: in java:
System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PATH"));
result:
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin

Comment: On my machine, the java binary takes the path that was in $PATH when you start Java. If it's different on your machine, then you have a Unix (probably Linux) issue, possibly with the way you start Java, or maybe you started your application from your .profile before you set the PATH. It's hard to tell without a lot more information (and probably out of scope for SO). But as an immediate resolution/workaround, you can add to your PATH within Java (by passing an `env` variable to `exec`)

Answer (score 0):

in my terminal:
as@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH;
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/as/hadoop/bin:/home/as/hadoop/sbin:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin:/home/as/sqoop-1.4.5.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha/bin:/home/as/hbase/bin:/home/as/hive/bin
but in java:
System.out.println(System.getenv().get("PATH"));

> > > Result:
> > >       /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/as/bin:/home/as/jdk1.8.0_25/bin
> > >       so this is $PATH of my account with $PATH of root?
> > >       so how to fix it?